# libogg Build error when trying to compile with vcpkg

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, libraries, vcpkg

```
package: libogg[core]:x86-windows-static -> 1.3.5
vcpkg-tool version: 2022-03-09-1affd32f93b299d5a907816c328ca3ededb73a7e
vcpkg-scripts version: unknown
```

Trying to install this libraries:

```
.\vcpkg.exe install boost-iostreams:x86-windows-static boost-asio:x86-windows-static boost-beast:x86-windows-static boost-system:x86-windows-static boost-variant:x86-windows-static boost-lockfree:x86-windows-static boost-process:x86-windows-static boost-program-options:x86-windows-static luajit:x86-windows-static glew:x86-windows-static boost-filesystem:x86-windows-static boost-uuid:x86-windows-static physfs:x86-windows-static openal-soft:x86-windows-static libogg:x86-windows-static libvorbis:x86-windows-static zlib:x86-windows-static libzip:x86-windows-static openssl:x86-windows-static
```

I'm getting this error in Windows 10:

```
Starting package 1/7: libogg:x86-windows-static
Building package libogg[core]:x86-windows-static...
-- Using community triplet x86-windows-static. This triplet configuration is not guaranteed to succeed.
-- [COMMUNITY] Loading triplet configuration from: C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\GitHub\otcv8-dev\vcpkg\triplets\community\x86-windows-static.cmake
-- Using cached xiph-ogg-v1.3.5.tar.gz.
-- Cleaning sources at C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/GitHub/otcv8-dev/vcpkg/buildtrees/libogg/src/v1.3.5-1a4243fef9.clean. Use --editable to skip cleaning for the packages you specify.
-- Extracting source C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/GitHub/otcv8-dev/vcpkg/downloads/xiph-ogg-v1.3.5.tar.gz
-- Using source at C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/GitHub/otcv8-dev/vcpkg/buildtrees/libogg/src/v1.3.5-1a4243fef9.clean
-- Found external ninja('1.11.0').
-- Configuring x86-windows-static
-- Building x86-windows-static-dbg
-- Building x86-windows-static-rel
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:158 (message):
    Command failed: C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/GitHub/otcv8-dev/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.22.2-windows/cmake-3.22.2-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe --build . --config Release --target install -- -v -j17
    Working Directory: C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/GitHub/otcv8-dev/vcpkg/buildtrees/libogg/x86-windows-static-rel
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\GitHub\otcv8-dev\vcpkg\buildtrees\libogg\install-x86-windows-static-rel-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_build_cmake.cmake:106 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_install_cmake.cmake:44 (vcpkg_build_cmake)
  ports/libogg/portfile.cmake:20 (vcpkg_install_cmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:145 (include)


Error: Building package libogg:x86-windows-static failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `git pull` and `.\vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+libogg
You can submit a new issue at:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[libogg]+Build+error
including:
  package: libogg[core]:x86-windows-static -> 1.3.5
    vcpkg-tool version: 2022-03-09-1affd32f93b299d5a907816c328ca3ededb73a7e
    vcpkg-scripts version: unknown

Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.
```

How can I install those libraries? I'm using a specific vcpkg commit for the program I'm trying to build because it's specified in it's readme: https://github.com/OTCv8/otcv8-dev

I know there is other people compiling this without issues

Comment: *"See logs for more information:"* Did you look in the logs?

Comment: where I can see the logs?

Comment: It tells you the log path in the error message, right after the part I quoted.

Comment: OMG! How I could read the error and didn't see that part... the problem was the Windows defender blocking the process... it's working fine now... how dumb...